# How to stop R from converting an arrow symbol (→) to a question mark?

Tags: r

I'm new to R and Stack Overflow, so apologies for any mistakes.

I'm reading data from an excel file using `read.table()`, and there are arrow symbols(→) in the file that are being converted to question marks in my plots. I've looked it up, and I've tried changing encoding to `fileEncoding="UTF-8"`, I've tried `check.names = FALSE`, and I've tried `as.is = TRUE` in my `read.table()` call.

Does anyone know how to make R recognize the right arrow symbol(→)?

Thank you!

Comment: post what code you are using for plotting and what the table looks like

Answer (score 1):

You need to let the plot function know '->' is a symbol. You can do this by using `expression()`

Fx:

```
plot(x, xlab = expression(x %->% something))
```